# Entity Framework 6 how to save entity with with two foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework

There are entities. Page can belong to Site or to PageBlock but not to both of them at the same time. Also here there is a cicular reference: `Page->Row->PageBlock->Page->Row->PageBlock...` The question about saving to database.

Page

```
public class Page {
    public virtual List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    public virtual int? SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? BlockId { get; set; }
}
```

Row

```
public class Row {
    public virtual List<AbstractBuildBlock> BuildBlocks { get; set; }
}
```

PageBlock

```
public class PageBlock : AbstractBuildBlock {
    public Page PageContent{ get; set; }
}
```

If `page` is added from `Site` object `BlockId` should be `null` and `SiteId` is setted, and if from `PageBlock` : `BlockId - NOT NULL`, `SiteId - NULL`.

While updating `Page` or `PageBlock` I set foreign keys manually because I know `PageId, BlockId`.

But when I add new `"PageOwnerEntity"` I don't know the it's Id, I rely on EF6 and do the next:

```
public int Add(Page obj)
    {
        if(obj.Id == 0 || obj.Id >= 10000) //Id >=10000 - object was created at client side
        //but at this moment I don't know what Id will be set to obj after it will be added to db
        {
            context.Pages.Add(obj); //Id auto-increment
        }else
        {
            //here update
        }
    }
```

For this input

```
Site { NewPage1 }
PageBlock { NewPage2 }
```

I have this output

```
Site { Id:1, PageId:1 }
PageBlock {Id:1, PageId:2 } //Interesting that PageId for PageBlock was setted                        
                                             ^
Page1 { Id: 1, SiteId: 1, BlockId: null}     | 
Page2 { Id: 2, SiteId: 1, BlockId: null}//but another end of relationship missed :(
```

I need

```
Site { Id:1, PageId:1 }
PageBlock {Id:1, PageId:2 }
Page1 { Id: 1, SiteId: 1, BlockId: null}
Page2 { Id: 2, SiteId: null, BlockId: 1}
```

Does anyone know any solution for this problem?

Comment: did you have tried to disable the cascade deleting between them?

Comment: @BassamAlugili Yes, now I'm searching for the way to stop cascade adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally disabling cascade deleting is not recommeded from microsoft but you can do that:

1) Disable cascade deleting for the whole application:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   // Related to your entities with m..n      
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

   // Related to your entities with 1..n              
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
   ....
```

2) Disable cascade deleting for locally for one relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()
         .HasOptional(c => c.Rows)
         .WithMany()
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Row>()
         .HasOptional(c => c.BuildBlocks)
         .WithMany()
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Your entities model for me is a little bit strange maybe you can configure it a more clearly to avoid like those problems.

Comment: The question helps, but finally I've simplified the data model.